# Android navigation drawer - two levels

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am looking to replicate the iOS app my company makes and on tablet in landscape they have a second nav drawer slide out from the first for the second level of categories.

e.g. in the first level they have clothes, shoes, accessories, then if you click clothes a second one appears scrolling to the right from the far right of the first nav bar, that then shows things like shirts, t-shirt, jeans, jumpers etc.

Is this possible in android? And if so, is it the accepted way of doing things?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, It is possbile. But it is not a practise using in android.
If you want to implement this design, the best way is to use two fragments instead of navigation drawer and use FragmentTrasation to provide the animations.

Comment: I think from what I'm told by the iOS team, it's not a standard practice in iOS either, it's just something they've designed for their app and would be nice if I could replicate it too. So you think two fragments (and I guess a third for content) instead of a drawerlayout and a second frag?

Comment: you can implement this using navigation drawer also. Make navigation drawer as the first layer, then display the fragment according to the choices in the navigation drawer

Comment: SathMK I think this is what I'll do. However, the new navigation has been lowered in priority and I've got other things to be getting on with for a few weeks. I'll use this stuff again in a few weeks (and no doubt have more questions then!)

Answer (score 2):

> on tablet in landscape they have a second nav drawer slide out from the first for the second level of categories.

That's not a nav drawer, then, at least [as defined by Google](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

> Is this possible in android?

Sure, just not using `DrawerLayout`. Execute a `FragmentTransaction` to slide in the second list adjacent to the first list, neither of which are in a `DrawerLayout`.

> And if so, is it the accepted way of doing things?

For a two-tier structure, I suspect that you will see other patterns used:

- `ExpandableListView`
- tabs for the first tier, and simpler master-detail for the second tier
- action bar list navigation for the first tier, and simpler master-detail for the second tier
- etc.

I can't even rule out `DrawerLayout` as being the implementation of the first tier (with traditional master-detail for the second tier), though the stuff in that list does not strike me as fitting the usage pattern for a navigation drawer.

Comment: just to give some more background, the app is a high end fashion/retail app. So on the home page of the phone app, you just have 4 buttons to take you to Clothes, Shoes, Accessories or Home and Tech, so in essence they are the top level pages. 

There is, collapsible drawerlayout which looks like an ExpandableListView, but I'm not sure how that would look if we have about 10-15 sub categories of clothing.

I'm not sure the tabs would quite fit the 'high end glorious nature' of the app/company, but I'll throw it out.

Comment: Mark, sorry I accepted @SathMK answer as he beat you by a few minutes in his reply, you have way more rep than him so I felt it good to spread it about a bit, and you both more or less said the same thing. I.e. no it can't be down with DrawerLayout, and that I'll have to use Fragment Transaction. I've upvoted you for giving more details though, to which I am grateful